# Google Cloud App Engine Service, API calls

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have two services on App Engine.

1. A static Angular 2 site.
2. An API.

At the moment I can only get at the static Angular site through the custom domain, how do I access the API through the custom domain?

I don't want to hard code the `appspot.com` address into my static site...

Thanks!

Comment: are you using cloud endpoints?

Comment: @MichaelMeyer nope. I've solved the problem using `dispatch.yaml` to route `*/api` calls to my api service. Not sure if this is the right way, works for now!